# Change "Available" in the IEEE 2006 Office bibliography style

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, bibliography

I have already made some changes to the IEEE 2006 format but I haven't found a way to change this bit.

I'm writing in Spanish so instead of saying "Available" it should say "Disponible en".

This is how it looks now when being use:

> T. Berners-Lee, "Semantic Web Road map," 14 Septiembre 1998. [En
>   línea]. Available: https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Semantic.html.
>   [Último acceso: 29 Julio 2018].

All the bits in brackets do get correctly translated.

[Here you can download the version of the style I'm using](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WWhw9U5_QJuwsqUTBln_bJbwXk7YjTNy/view?usp=sharing).

I'm using Office 2016.

Comment: What version of Office are you using.  Newer versions of Office allow you to install any language pack you want.  Ultimately I would create the citation page manually if the automatic one isn’t in the language you want.

Comment: @Ramhound Office 2016

Comment: So have you installed the appropriate language pack?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, I have the appropriate language pack but it doesn't seem to be enough